# Golang translates text to the next line

Tags: go, concatenation

I trying to send POST request, but during concatenation go translates text to the next line.
As you can see, \n is added at the end of the url.
What to think about it?
How to fix it?
[image: code]

[image]

Comment: The string `b.PhoneSeven` contains a `\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b.PhoneSeven` ends with `"\n"`.
Try `strings.TrimSpace(b.PhoneSeven)`.

https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimSpace